# Generate and view the dynamically created pdf using iTextSharp in c# using MVC framework

Tags: c#, getjson

Is it possible to generate the pdf dynamically using iTextSharp and view it in a new window through a Json call?

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage in doing this with Json unless the JSON request is going to do some checking or testing. I suggest to create a special HttpHandler which upon receiving a request, generates the PDF and returns it back to the browser. This way you can have a hyperlink which will open a new window and shows the pdf in it:

```
<a href="link to the handler" target="_blank">Open PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use Json? I think there is an easiest way. Ex:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("View pdf","GeneratePdf","YourController" new{}, new{target="_blank"}) %>
```

In your controller

```
public ActionResult GeneratePdf()
{
     Document pdfDocument = new Document();
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument,stream); 
     //add some code to generate your pdf content
     pdfDocument.Close();
     return new FileResult(stream,"application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: actually there are around 25 parameters being passed via json call to the server. based on those values a report has to be generated. if i go for an actionlink, all those params will be displayed in the url. is tht rite? plz suggest..

Comment: You can use Html.BeginForm instead of actionlink and pass your aprameters as hidden input. Or make a jquery ajax request with your parameters.

Comment: will making a $.getJSON() request be able to pop up the pdf in a new window? if yes, could you please share more info on this..